# How to customize individual field in collection, symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I need to customize how field in collection is drawn.

I have entity A:

```
class A {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="B", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $b;
    ...
}
```

and entity B:

```
class B {
    ...
    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cs", type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cs;
    ...
}
```

I have form types:

```
class AType {
    ...
    ->add(
        'b',
        new BType(),
        array(
            'label' => false
        )
    )
    ...
}

class BType {
    ...
    ->add(
        "cs",
        "collection",
        array(
            "type" => "hidden",
            'label' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'data' => array(1,2,3),
        )
    ...
}
```

Now, what I need is to customize how items in cs are drawn. I googled a bit and try few options what to put into my form theme:

```
{% block _NAME_ %}
{% endblock %}
```

with *NAME*

```
_a_b_cs_widget
_b_cs_widget
_cs_widget
_atype_b_cs_widget
_atype_btype_cs_widget
_btype_cs_widget
```

and few others, now have worked. Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct is:

```
_a_b_cs_entry_widget
```